# Recent install of ArchLinux not loading

Tags: arch-linux, boot, system-installation

I recently installed ArchLinux (because hey, why not) and used the Arch install script and installer located here https://github.com/helmuthdu/aui.

After doing this, I got to the boot screen and it took a while, the first time it said "Loading kernel modules" and then the same message appeared again. waited for it for roughly half an hour, and it just hung there.

Hardware is a Dell Inspiron 15R with intel i5, 6GB RAM, 64bit. It *is* UEFI, if it matters.

Does anyone know how to fix this so I could try and re-install it again?

Comment: Use the [Beginners' Guide on the Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners%27_guide); it will be up-to-date and if you follow it methodically and completly is unlikely to lead you to be in the postion you find yourself now...

Comment: I have no second computer to read the guide on. I have tried to download it as plaintext and read it from a usb while installing, but it references other pages on the wiki.

Is there a main page that covers everything?

Comment: There are actually packages that you can install on the live media: [arch-wiki-lite](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/any/arch-wiki-lite/) and [arch-wiki-docs](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/any/arch-wiki-docs/).

Comment: The live media also inlcudes the elinks browser, just open another TTY and point it to the wiki...

Comment: @slm, posted as-requested.

Comment: As explained, the official documentation is the way to go. Otherwise you can take a look at [Archbang](http://wiki.archbang.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) for a minimalistic preconfigured Arch-like Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using unofficial install scripts and guides are typically a recipe for unhappiness under Arch Linux. As [recommended](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139824/recent-install-of-arch-linux-not-loading?noredirect=1#comment225650_139824) by @jasonwryan, you should really just follow the [Beginners' Guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners%27_guide) on the ArchWiki.

If you do not have access to another computer on which to keep the Wiki page open, you can actually install one of two packages which provide (fairly) up-to-date versions of the wiki locally: [arch-wiki-lite](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/any/arch-wiki-lite/) and [arch-wiki-docs](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/any/arch-wiki-docs/).

Alternatively, you can simply switch to another TTY and run `elinks` (a text-based web browser provided with the Arch Install Media) and view the Guide live.

Note, if you have an Android device, there is actually a community-contributed [application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jtmcn.archwiki.viewer) that you can use to follow along the guide.

Comment: Can anyone give me a quick detail on how to switch to another TTY? I don't even know what a tty is.

Comment: A VTT is a virtual terminal (what you're presented with when you first boot the Arch Install Media is a VTT). You can typically switch among available VTTs under *nix OSs using `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `F#` where `#` is a number from 1–6.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I'm not ready for Arch if I don't know these things, but I'll save this post for later.

Comment: `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `F#` is an X thing really, outside of X you'd normally just use `Alt` + `F#`

Comment: `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F#` works on VTTs just fine.